# Installing ExactTarget on Developer Edition

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is it possible to install Salesforce Marketing Cloud (ExactTarget) on a developer edition?

Or this can be done only on Production instance ?

Comment: I have installed in sandbox with on problem, I think it's ok to install in any SFDC edition, the access is controlled at ETMC side.

Comment: @ling : sry..did you mean "no problem" or "one problem"...tx

Answer (score 2):

Marketing Cloud Developer Edition accounts were announced at Connections 2014 and were available for a limited period after the event. If you signed up for one at this time, it will work, but you can't register for new accounts at this time.

so,It is not possible to install Salesforce Marketing Cloud (ExactTarget) on a developer edition for free.